Running the Android application (Java) after closing, Android studio
I wrote a program in Java that first takes the user's working days using checkboxes and then retrieves the working hours for each day.
If the user is within their working day and hours, a break sound plays at minutes 25 and 55, and if the minutes are 00 or 30, a work sound plays. The hours and days are stored in SharedPreferences, and after the first login, the user is always directed to the 'ProActivity'
The program works well and correctly, but I want it to continue running even after the user completely closes the app, like an alarm clock!
I have provided the code for the mentioned activity below:

    private void checkWorkStatus() {
        // گرفتن تاریخ و ساعت فعلی
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDay = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", new Locale("fa")).format(calendar.getTime());
        String currentHour = String.format("%02d:00 - %02d:00",
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1) % 24);

        int currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // گرفتن ساعات کاری ذخیره‌شده برای روز جاری
        Set<String> workHours = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(currentDay, null);

        if (workHours == null || workHours.isEmpty()) {
            tvStatus.setText("تعطیل");
        } else if (!workHours.contains(currentHour)) {
            tvStatus.setText("کار شروع نشده");
            resetFlags(); // ریست پرچم‌ها اگر ساعت فعلی در ساعت کاری نباشد
        } else {
            // بررسی دقیقه‌های مختلف و تغییر متن لیبل
            if (currentMinute == 25 || currentMinute == 29 || currentMinute == 55 || currentMinute == 59) {
                tvStatus.setText("استراحت :)");
                // فقط یکبار در دقیقه‌های مشخص شده آهنگ استراحت پخش می‌شود
                playOnceAtMinute(currentMinute, "rest");
            } else if (currentMinute == 0 || currentMinute == 24 || currentMinute == 30 || currentMinute == 54) {
                tvStatus.setText("کار :(");
                // فقط یکبار در دقیقه‌های مشخص شده آهنگ کار پخش می‌شود
                playOnceAtMinute(currentMinute, "work");
            } else {
                tvStatus.setText("کار");
                resetFlags(); // ریست پرچم‌ها وقتی دقیقه مشخص نیست
            }
        }
    }

    private void playOnceAtMinute(int minute, String soundType) {
        if ("rest".equals(soundType)) {
            if ((minute == 25 && !isPlayedAt25) || (minute == 55 && !isPlayedAt55)) {
                restPlayer.start(); // پخش آهنگ استراحت
                if (minute == 25) {
                    isPlayedAt25 = true;
                } else if (minute == 55) {
                    isPlayedAt55 = true;
                }
            }
        } else if ("work".equals(soundType)) {
            if ((minute == 30 && !isPlayedAt30) || (minute == 0 && !isPlayedAt00)) {
                workPlayer.start(); // پخش آهنگ کار
                if (minute == 30) {
                    isPlayedAt30 = true;
                } else if (minute == 0) {
                    isPlayedAt00 = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


You would need to use AlarmManager, taking into account its limitations.
